# Java Game error (Array, this. , methods)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game

{

    private String startYorN;
    private int generateTestValues;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private int minCanisters;
    private int maxCanisters;
    private int numOfDarkies;
    private int minimumLifePoints;
    private String name;
    private String type1;
    private int sPosition1, sPosition2;
    private int tPosition1, tPosition2;
    private int iLifePoints;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void gameSetting()
    {

        System.out.print ("Would you like to play? (y/n):");
        startYorN = scan.nextLine();
        //if (startYorN =="n" || startYorN =="N")
        //quit the game(?)

        System.out.print ("Would you want to generate test values for world? 1- yes: ");
        generateTestValues =scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("");

        System.out.print ("Enter a number of rows for world: ");
        rows = scan.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("");

        System.out.print ("Enter a number of cols for world: ");
        cols = scan.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("");

        System.out.print ("Enter minimum energy canisters in each planet: ");
        minCanisters = scan.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("");

        System.out.print ("Enter maximum energy canisters in each planet: ");
        maxCanisters = scan.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("");

        System.out.print ("Enter number of planets with darkies: ");
        numOfDarkies = scan.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("");

        System.out.print ("Enter minimum life points for players to replenish: ");
        minimumLifePoints = scan.nextInt ();
        System.out.print ("\n");
        World w = new World(rows,cols,minCanisters, maxCanisters, numOfDarkies);
        w.display();

        Alien[] alien = new Alien [2];

        for (int i = 0; i<=1;i++)
        {   
            name = scan.nextLine ();
            System.out.print ("\n");
            System.out.print ("Enter name for player #" + i + ": ");
            name = scan.nextLine ();

            System.out.print ("Enter kind Player #" + i + ", (n- naive, g- greedy, a- aggressive, u- naive user, w-aggressive user): ");
            type = scan.nextLine ();

            System.out.print ("Enter: row (space) column for start position for player #" + i + ": ");
            sPosition1 = scan.nextInt ();
            sPosition2 = scan.nextInt ();

            System.out.print ("Enter: row (space) column for target position for player #" + i + ": ");
            tPosition1 = scan.nextInt ();
            tPosition2 = scan.nextInt ();

            System.out.print ("Enter initial life points for player #" + i + ": ");
            iLifePoints = scan.nextInt ();
        }
    }
    public void setInfo(Alien alien[i], String name, String type, int sPosition1, int sPosition2,
                        int tPosition1, int tPosition2, int iLifePoints)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.sPosition1 = sPosition1;
        this.sPosition2 = sPosition2;
        this.tPosition1 = tPosition1;
        this.tPosition2 = tPosition2;
        this.iLifePoints = iLifePoints;
    }
}
```

I know there's something wrong in the setInfo method and probably in the gameSetting method too. I want to get the information from each of two players(aliens). Could somebody please tell me what I should do?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is this the complete code? I'm confused :(

Comment: where ur using Alien alien[i] in setInfo

Comment: We need more code and/or errors you're getting to help you.

Comment: I am getting so many ']' expected, ';' expected, illegal start of type, and <identifier> expected errors in the public void setInfo method.. This is just a part of the whole class, but I could edit and post the whole thing.

Comment: try pasting the entire stack trace.  if you're getting ] and ; expected errors, chances are you haven't closed off an array type and a line is missing in the semicolon.  Check the code in your IDE, it should have the lines marked where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is you should remove the `i` in `Alien alien[i]` in your `setInfo()` argument list. You might also want to consider removing it from the argument list entirely as you don't use it, or perhaps not using it is another mistake you need to fix.

You also need to change the declaration of variable `type1` to call it `type` instead, as that's what you use in several places further down.

Fixing those two issues removes all compiler errors except for the "Class not found" for Scanner/Alien/World, but you can hopefully fix those. See http://ideone.com/PNqb2

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void setInfo(Alien alien[], String name, String type, int sPosition1, int
sPosition2, int tPosition1, int tPosition2, int iLifePoints)
```

You were trying to pass on a specific instance of Alien from the array, but Java doesn't let you do that.  When calling the setInfo(), just access the proper Alien instance and pass it on.

Also, you should add more info about the errors, preferably the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

Remove "Alien alien[i]" from setInfo.  It's unused.  If you are using it, then figure out what it is.  If it's an Alien array it should be Alien[] alien, if it's a single alien, it should just be Alien alien.  If it's the index into an instance array, it should just be int alien

Also, using (position1, position2) is gonna get confusing really fast.  Stick with row,col or you'll forget what order they go in (notice (x,y) and (row, col) are opposite orders.  And (width,height) is the same as (x,y))